# Перегруженный Оператор >> для сдвига столбцов матрицы на K позиций

Tags: c++, классы, матрицы, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Не могу реализовать оператор >> для сдвига столбцов матрицы на K. Позиций. Общее задание звучит так:

1 В матрице С найти сумму элементов и переменную в которой будет эта сумма приводите к типу int чтобы для нее можно было произвести побитовую инверсию. В результате получаем целое число.

2  Для матрицы А циклический сдвиг столбцов вправо на количество позиций, вычисленное в пункте один, получая матрицу А1

3 В матрице В и  матрице А находим максимальные элементы, а из них выбираем минимальный, который приводим к целому числу.

4 Для полученной в п.2 матрицы А1 производим циклический сдвиг столбцов вправо на количество позиций полученных в п.3.

Прилагаю код: [Извиняюсь за ссылку с cpp проектом, а за не код, редактор не даёт ввести корректно код целиком](https://yadi.sk/d/nc8FByEl_GK4Lw)

Comment: Не по вопросу - но у вас утечка памяти - вы забываете удалять все `X[i]` перед удалением `X`...

Answer (score 1):

```
void reverse(int** matrix, int n, int m,
             int start, int stop)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(int b = start, e = stop; b < e; ++b, --e)
        {
            int tmp = matrix[i][b];
            matrix[i][b] = matrix[i][e];
            matrix[i][e] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
Matr operator >> (int K) //Оператор сдвига матрицы на K позиций вправо
{
    cout << "Операция >> \n" << endl;
    Matr z(*this);
    reverse(z.X,z.n,z.m,0,z.m-K-1);
    reverse(z.X,z.n,z.m,z.m-K,z.m-1);
    reverse(z.X,z.n,z.m,0,z.m-1);
    return z;
}

....

A1 = A >> 2; //Вызов оператора, смеющего матрицу на К значений, и создаюего матрицу А1
A1.PrintAll();
```

Примерно так. Но у вас есть и другие ошибки, например, в деструкторе вы освобождаете не всю память, используете параллельно `delete` и `free`, не совсем последовательно работаете с `const` - это то, что бросилось в глаза. Специально весь код не смотрел.

Comment: Вставил код, и попробовал, запустить, выдает ошибку о необработанном исключении, может что-то не-то в вызовах функций?

Comment: Убедитесь, что работает: https://ideone.com/mErkb9 А если вы начинаете, например, сдвигать матрицу в 5 столбцов на 15 элементов - кто ж вам виноват? Приведите к нужному диапазону...

Comment: Можете подсказать, как это сделать? А то не могу додумать =(

Comment: А разве нельзя сделать сдвиг цикличным? например, если мы сдвигаем матрицу  5 на 5 на 15 элементов, она сдвигается 3 раза циклично

Comment: Вот! Я и намекаю на это - сами пересчитайте, что 15%5 == 0, и сдвигать не надо. Потому что если вы подставите 15 во вспомогательную функцию `reverse`, то выскочите далеко за пределы массива. И если бы вы постарались не *переписать*, а *понять* решение, то сообразили бы это и сами...

Comment: Понял, сначала не догнал, думал, зачем мы с остатком делим

Comment: Ну, тогда, если все OK и ответ устроил - можете принимать :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но препода это как всегда не устроило =( Пришлось переделывать функцию, что бы она циклично сдвигала матрицу, без использования деления без остатка, но спасибо за помощь =). Кстати, так и не понял, зачем мы 3 раза вызывали функцию сдвига?

Comment: Не сдвига, а *реверса* - классический алгоритм циклического сдвига, видимо, ваш препод - увы! - не читал ["Жемчужины программирования"](http://padabum.com/x.php?id=9697) - там этот метод описан на стр. 32-34 (кстати, крайне рекомендую почитать всю книгу). Если он с вас потребовал N раз переносить на один шаг, мне вас (а его особенно) просто жалко...